# Simple way of replacing a parts of NSMutableString/NSString

Tags: objective-c, str-replace

I am new to iPhone development (using iOS 5) and I am trying to replace `:` with spaces in an NSMutableString. I have been struggling with this since an hour and it forces me to use 
`replaceOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@" " options:nil range:;` (I thought I could use it without options and range). I have tried almost everything (especially for the `range` parameter) but it keeps complaining about various stuff such as `bad receiver type`.

Any suggestions about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how you invoke `replaceOccurrencesOfString:` to produce the desired effect:

```
[myString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@":"
                          withString:@" "
                             options:NSLiteralSearch
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, myString.length)];
```